# how can I store value from sqlDataReader? and to compare?

Tags: c#, mysql, datareader

```
int availableSeat = 0;
string query = "select flight_no flight_seat from flight_info where flight_departure_time = @selectedFlight AND flight_from = @flightFrom AND flight_to = @flightTo ";
string url = "Server=localhost;Database=flight;uid=******;password=*****";
con1 = new MySqlConnection(url);
con1.Open();
cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query,con1);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selectedFlight",comboBox3.SelectedItem);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flightFrom",comboBox1.SelectedItem);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flightTo",comboBox2.SelectedItem);
reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read()) 
{
    availableSeat.Equals(reader["flight_seat"]);
    if(availableSeat > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The seat is available!!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, all seat has been booked!!");
    }
}
con1.Close();
```

As you can see here, I would like to store `flight_seat` column from SQL into `availableSeat` in order to check whether there is a seat available.

How can I do that? because it keeps going to else.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
availableSeat = (int)reader["flight_seat"]);
```

The `Equals()` method is used for comparison purposes (equality) and not assignment. Furthermore, assignments are done in C# by setting the variable on the left of the `=` to the result of the statement on the right.

You need to cast the value in the `reader` to an `int` because it is stored as an `object`. You should also check for a `null` value since this is coming from a database:

```
availableSeat = reader["flight_seat"].Equals(DBNull.Value)
                    ? 0
                    : (int)reader["flight_seat"];
```

Comment: Umm, I think there is a problem. It says "An exeption of type System.invalidCaseException was thrown :\nSpecified cast is not valid"

Comment: Then your `flight_seat` is not an `int` value. You should check what the underlying type is in the MySQL database. For example, if it's some type of `varchar` you'll need to define `availableSeat` as a `string` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`availableSeat.Equals()` is a comparison not an assignment. You would need to assign the value. For example

```
availableSeat = (int)reader["flight_seat"];
```